# Can I change the Field Label Length in Solspace Freeform

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I have a composer template in freeform pro, thats being used as a survey. The field label needs to be a question which is quite long but there appears to be a limit on the field label in Freeform. Can this be changed?

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit in the label field in the CP: if you look at the source code, you will see the input field has an attribute: `maxlength="150"`. That limits the field to entering 150 characters.

Even if you changed that value temporarily using the Web Inspector or Firebug in your browser, in the `exp_freeform_fields` database table, the field_label column is VARCHAR(150), which means that beyond 150 characters, the database cuts off text to 150 characters. You would have to make a change in the database as well, which is something we would recommend being *very* careful with if you're not familiar with MySQL (we can't advocate doing that).

Since you need more text and instead of doing the above hacks, how about using the **Field Description** field to hold your label text? That field can hold a lot more text (65000+ characters actually), and you can swap it with your label in the template code.